# Passing objects from python to powershell

Tags: python, powershell, scripting-language

I want to have an integration between my python scripts and my powershell scripts.
For that I need the option to pass object of class I made so powershell could work with it.

That class contains string type properties and one object property that contains None or a pointer to object of another classes I made that contains only string properties.

What is the best way to do that task? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest might be to encode the object as a JSON string in Python, and then convert it to a PowerShell object with `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: What is the right way to encode all of my classes to JSON? Is there a python library that does it like powershell has?

Comment: @user3482697, Python has very good documentation. Why don't you look in the Python Library Reference?